# How can I make random into order Javascript?

Tags: javascript, random

I have this code which is used to change the image displayed on every page reload randomly. I'm not very experienced in JavaScript, so can someone help me make this code change the image on reload in order instead of randomly?

Here is the Code:

```
function showImage(){
    var theImages = new Array()

    theImages[0] = '100.jpg'
    theImages[1] = '200.jpg'
    theImages[2] = '300.jpg'
    theImages[3] = '400.jpg'
    theImages[4] = '500.png'

    var j = 0
    var p = theImages.length;

    var preBuffer = new Array()
    for (i = 0; i < p; i++){
       preBuffer[i] = new Image()
       preBuffer[i].src = theImages[i]
    }

    var whichImage = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1));
    function showImage(){
    document.write('<img src="'+theImages[whichImage]+'">');
}
```

And then I simply call the image in the body with this:

```
showImage();
```

Comment: Maybe off topic but you should list out your array in brackets. var theImages = ['100.jpg', '200.jpg'] ... etc. It's easier and more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will show them in order and repeat at the beginning once they are all the way through.

```
(function(){
    var list = [
            "100.jpg",
            "200.jpg",
            "300.jpg",
            "400.jpg",
            "500.jpg"
        ],i = localStorage.image || 0;
    document.write('<img src="'+list[i]+'"/>');
    i++;
    i%=list.length;
    localStorage.image = i;
})();
```

Here's a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/J9gAD/

Nobody (jsbin, jsfiddle, codepen) seems to support document.write, understandably, so the fiddle shows how to change the src value of an img tag instead of writing the element insitu.

To do this with HTML content (in a div)...
http://jsfiddle.net/J9gAD/2/

Comment: To start the sequence with the 1st image rather than the 2nd one, you'll need to either (a) change `|| 0` to `|| -1`, or (b) move `i++;` and `localStorage.image = i;` to the bottom of the function.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, i feel i should mention im quite new to javascript, so i tried copying and pasting the example you gave me here, not the jsbin example, but no image appeared, i have the images with the correct names in the same folder as the html page, any idea why?

Comment: Try that. I realized that you are writing this image in place. Usually you place an img tag or some kind of container in your html someplace and then once everything has loaded update the tag. This should work.

Comment: Wow, flawless thank you so much, i'm verry greatfull of people like you around helping!   I know it mite seem like a bit much, but by any chance do you also know how to change not only an image, instead change a whole div with a link in it and an image? I understand you might not want to help on this one, but i just want to avoid posting another question, thanks Shanimal your answer is the best one, will select after you reply to this second question, you can just say no if you want, thanks again!

Comment: I've added how to do that with sincerest hope that your endeavor is to someday become the best Javascript programmer on earth and that you'll mention me as an inspiration in your yet unpublished Orielly Book. Best of luck to both of us ;)

Comment: lol actually i am planning on mastering JS but first im focusing on PHP, i'm verry greatfull of helpfull people like you in the world, keep it up! Thanks again and yes good luck to us!

Comment: Hey Shanimal, is there something else i have to do besides pasting the code to use the code? I copied an pasted all the code you provided (To see it work on my computer)  when i test it screen is blank nothing show on page, any steps to take? It works just fin in Jfiddle

Comment: If you right click on the "result pane" you'll see it all put together.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to show in order on page reload (which is a bit odd, but okay), you'll need to pass the index to the url, so something like

```
function showImage(){
    var theImages = new Array()

    theImages[0] = '100.jpg'
    theImages[1] = '200.jpg'
    theImages[2] = '300.jpg'
    theImages[3] = '400.jpg'
    theImages[4] = '500.png'

    var j = 0
    var p = theImages.length;

    var preBuffer = new Array()
    for (i = 0; i < p; i++){
       preBuffer[i] = new Image()
       preBuffer[i].src = theImages[i]
    }

    var index = location.hash || 0;
    if (index >= p) index = 0;

    var img = document.createElement('img'); 
    img.src = theImages[index];

    //replace document.body here with a reference to where you want the image to go
    document.body.appendChild(img); 
    location.hash = index++;
}
```

If you're using location.hash for other things you'll have to do some manual parsing of it, that's not very hard.

Comment: That won't work. On the first call to document.write after the page has loaded, it will delete the entire content of the page except for what is written by document.write.

Comment: @RobG - Good catch, I never use document.write. Anyway I edited to fix.

Comment: hi i tried your code, but instead of the picture showing up, i get the small image "icon" representing there is supposed to be a picture there, i inspected element and it states "undefined" any idea?

Comment: Hey well i think i might not be setting it up correctly, i'm not experienced in JS code, so i'm not shure what you mean with this:    `//replace document.body here with a reference to where you want the image to go
    document.body.appendChild(img);`  i didn,t know what you ment but so this is how i tried it: the code you provided in a <script> tag in header and in body tag i added an <img> tag

Comment: you don't have to add an img tag in the body, that's what document.createElement, and document.appendChild do. If you inspect the image in chrome, what does is say the src attribute is?

Answer (score 0):

You have two showImage functions in your script... Which isn't right. But to get them to display in order just use theImages[i] in your for loop, and just get rid of the random bit. Unless you both, in which case,  make two functions: one for random and one for order. Like showImageRandom() and showImage().